# IPC between server and many clients on Mac OS X

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I have following scenario:

Server should be Daemon.
Other Apps should be clients.
Many clients should communicate with server to get their task done by server at a time.
These tasks are such as copyfile, deletefile etc.

My solution:
Server has 5 worker threads each containing named pipe. Each pipe's availability status is kept in Shared memory structure. When client wants to communicate with server, it checks which pipe is available from shared memory then opens that pipe & sends its message on that pipe, respective worker thread of server servers this client request. That worker thread sends request status (Success/failure) on that pipe so that client will become aware of last operation status.

As far as I know, pipes on Mac os x are unidirectional & they lack capability of creating unlimited instances like Windows.

What mechanism could be best suited for such kind of communication?

Thanks,
Vaibhav.

Comment: Are you sure, you want to reinvent the wheel?

Answer (score 1):

> As far as I know, pipes on Mac os x are unidirectional & they lack capability of creating unlimited instances like Windows.

Pipes are one directional, but [Unix sockets](http://beej.us/guide/bgipc/output/html/multipage/unixsock.html) are not.  This is probably what you are after if you want to directly port your code to OS X.

However, there are probably better ways to do what you want to do, including stuff like [Distributed Objects](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DistrObjects/DistrObjects.html) which I admit I have never used.  Even if you stick with a socket interface, I think one socket would be easier with a thread monitoring the socket and handing off work to worker threads as it arrives, using [listen](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/System/Conceptual/ManPages_iPhoneOS/man2/listen.2.html) and [accept](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/System/Conceptual/ManPages_iPhoneOS/man2/accept.2.html#//apple_ref/doc/man/2/accept).  Better still, have an NSOperationQueue or a dispatch queue to put the work on, then the OS will handle the task of optimising the thread count.